# How to create dynamic schema in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a collection of document in mongodb. Each document in it is having `book_type: "audio"`. `book_type` can be `audio | video | document`. If `book_type = audio` then there is `audio_url : [some-link]` in the document. For `video`, we have `video_url : [some-link]` in the document.

You can see that for different book type we have some additional parameters. Now, I want to draw schema for this in mongoose for `book_collection`. I have made a bookSchema for common keys & for video|audio|document type I have made corresponding schema like videoSchema.

How can I bind `videoSchema` with `bookSchema` based on `book_type` ?

```
const bookSchema = new Schema({
  name : String,
  thumbnail : String,
  book_type : String,
  content : videoSchema   //if book_type = "video"
})

const videoSchema = new Schema({
  stream_url : String,
  watch_time : Number
}

const audioSchema = new Schema({
  stream_url : String,
  audio_url: Number
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose schema lets you add the [required](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/schematype.html#SchemaType.prototype.required()) validator and allows you pass a function to check for another property value in your case. Have you considered altering your `bookSchema` to something like:

```
const bookSchema = new Schema({
  name : String,
  thumbnail : String,
  book_type : String,
  video_content : {
     type: videoSchema,
     required: function() { return this.book_type === 'video'; }
  },
  audio_content: {
     type: audioSchema,
     required: function() { return this.book_type === 'audio'; }
  }
})

const videoSchema = new Schema({
  stream_url : String,
  watch_time : Number
})

const audioSchema = new Schema({
  stream_url : String,
  audio_url: Number
})
```

This would only add a `video_content` property if the `book_type` is video and likewise, it would only add an `audio_content` if the `book_type` is audio.

Comment: Thank You for answer. I have gone through the documentation line by line and came out that discriminators is the best way for this problem. Because, In my case there can be multiple type `audio | video | pdf | docs | text` and for each type I don't think its a good idea to create a key for each. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html

Comment: Glad you found a solution. With that many possible schema types, discriminators looks like the best option.